# Display mat-label on custom mat-form-field component, angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm creating a custom input component to be used in my angular material forms, but assigning a `mat-label` in the form field where the component is used has no effect.

My component HTML is as follows:

```
<form *ngIf="val">
  <table>
    <td>
      +
    </td>
    <td>
      <input matInput
        id="country"
        type="text"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [(ngModel)]="val.country"
        class="input"
        placeholder="27"
        maxlength="2"
        (keyup)="phoneFieldFocusHandler($event)"
        required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input matInput
        id="area"
        type="text"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [(ngModel)]="val.area"
        class="input"
        placeholder="949"
        maxlength="3"
        (keyup)="phoneFieldFocusHandler($event)"
        required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input matInput
        id="prefix"
        type="text"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [(ngModel)]="val.prefix"
        class="input"
        placeholder="555"
        maxlength="3"
        (keyup)="phoneFieldFocusHandler($event)"
        required>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input matInput
        id="line"
        type="text"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [(ngModel)]="val.line"
        class="input"
        placeholder="5555"
        maxlength="4"
        (keyup)="phoneFieldFocusHandler($event)"
        required>
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

And the corresponding typescript:

```
import { coerceBooleanProperty } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { Component, forwardRef, HostBinding, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { PhoneNumber } from '../phone-number.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-input',
  templateUrl: './phone-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {       provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => PhoneInputComponent),
            multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MatFormFieldControl,
      useExisting: PhoneInputComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class PhoneInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<any> {

  @HostBinding('attr.id')
  externalId = '';

  val: PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();

  stateChanges = new Subject<void>();
  private _ID = '';
  /*tslint:disable-next-line*/
  _placeholder: string;
  /*tslint:disable-next-line*/
  _required: boolean;
  /*tslint:disable-next-line*/
  _disabled: boolean;
  ngControl: NgControl;
  focused: boolean;
  empty: boolean;
  shouldLabelFloat: boolean;
  errorState: boolean;
  userAriaDescribedBy?: string;

  @Input()
  set id(value: string) {
    this._ID = value;
    this.externalId = null;
  }

  get id(): string {
    return this._ID;
  }

  @Input()
  get placeholder(): string {
   return this._placeholder;
  }

  set placeholder(plh) {
   this._placeholder = plh;
   this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get required(): boolean {
    return this._required;
  }
  set required(req) {
    this._required = coerceBooleanProperty(req);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  @Input()
  get disabled(): boolean {
    return this._disabled;
  }
  set disabled(dis) {
    this._disabled = coerceBooleanProperty(dis);
    this.stateChanges.next();
  }

  setDescribedByIds(ids: string[]): void {
    this.userAriaDescribedBy = ids.join(' ');
  }

  onContainerClick(event: MouseEvent): void {}

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  // upon UI element value changes, this method gets triggered
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // upon touching the element, this method gets triggered
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};

  set value(val: PhoneNumber) {
    if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.onChange(val);
      this.onTouch(val);
    }
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.stateChanges.complete();
  }

  // Internally handle moving focus from one input to the next
  phoneFieldFocusHandler(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const target = e.target as any as HTMLInputElement;
    if (target.value.length >= target.maxLength) {
      const parent = target.parentElement.parentElement;
      const children = (Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children) as Array<HTMLElement>).map(el => el.children[0] as HTMLInputElement);
      const curr = children.indexOf(target);
      if (!(curr >= children.length - 1)) {
        children[curr + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

It is used in the form as:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
    <app-phone-input formControlName="phone"></app-phone-input>
</mat-form-field>
```

But the label is not displayed.

Do I need to define a space in my custom component where the label will be shown?